Trouble with QGIS .shp files and .dbf files
I am currently trying to add a series of files called "LotNumber", it has a .dbf and .shp file that has already been made on ArcMap. When I try to add a vector layer in QGIS and add either of the files, the location of the lots(coordinates) are in the correct locations, but none of the data follows. I have a table full of data about the lots that connect with other entities but none of the data gets inserted when I add the layer.

You should have more than the .dbf and .shp, shapefile need at last an .shx file to be functional (and a .prj is usefull)...

yes. shx (index file) is required.

A shapefile should also have an .shx file.
If it is missing, you can let QGIS regenerate it using the "Repair shapefile" tool.
The tool can be found in the QGIS "Processing toolbox": enable/show it via "Processing"/"Toolbox" in the menu, and search for "Repair shapefile":

